# Youtube/Firefox access to my history

Tags: privacy, web-browser, firefox

I recently noticed something weird. From time to time I watch on YouTube (Firefox) something political. In my case 'lastweektonight'(left) and 'StevenCrowder'(right), (because it is fun to see, where each party lies).
Anyway I noticed, when I watch a video from StevenCroder the next video in line, is always a video from lastweektonight. I think, I made myself look like an undecided voter...

Then it occurred to me, how can they do that, if I do not have an account? I deleted my YouTube browser history, nothing else, and checked again. I clicked on a video from stevencroder and the next video in line was one from stevencroder.
How can they read my browser history?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run your browser in private (or incognito) mode?

Comment: @mti2935 --- I'll check, but i need some time building up my history again.

Comment: Websites don't read your browser history. They usually have trackers that will [fingerprint your browser](https://www.amiunique.org/fp). Clearing your browser history doesn't affect websites or tracking. Clearing cookies will affect some tracking (and log you out of some sites), but it doesn't do much about your browser fingerprint.

Comment: @Fire Quacker --- That is what I thought as well. I know about Canvas & Cookies that are used to track people. However, once I deleted my browser history, the behavior of YouTube clearly changed and it is freaking me out.

Comment: @Myxir that's because you deleted your cookies

Comment: They use IP addresses. I get recommendations on things my roommates watch all the time.

Comment: @schroeder --- Do you mean, if I delete a website from my history, it automatically deletes the cookies that belong to that website? That could be it, I guess I need to revisit my cookies.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean because that's not what I understood you to mean. "I deleted my browser history" usually deletes cookies. "Deleting a website from my browser history" is something completely different. What did you do?

Comment: When I browse normally, then go to youtube, it clearly suggests videos related to other videos that I've watched on youtube during that browsing session.  However, once I close my browser, then start a new session in private mode, youtube no longer seems to recognize who I am (based on the videos that it suggests).

Comment: @schroeder ---  I open the history tab and right clicked on YouTube and clicked forget entire website.
On a side note I use a VPN, so they did not track me using my IP.

Comment: Your VPN still has an IP, and it's used by you, even if it's not geographically tied to your location, it's still an identifier.

Comment: @Myxir if you did it from the History tab, then it also deleted the cookies.

Comment: I did not watch the lastweektonight on the same day, different country on the vpn. I am not that stupid.

Comment: @schroeder --- Thanks schroeder, I was concerned that they tracked my entire browser history for years, while selling it left and right.

Comment: @Myxir not Firefox, but Youtube, certainly

Answer (score 2):

YouTube uses cookies which helps them track you and suggest videos even if you do not have an account.

But using the "Forget this site" from the History tab, you removed those cookies:

> Using "Forget About This Site" will remove all data stored in Firefox
>   from that domain like bookmarks, **cookies**, passwords, cache, history,
>   and exceptions [emphasis mine]

[source](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1059209)

So, no, YouTube did not have access to all your history, just your history on YouTube since they stored a cookie. Firefox has always had all your history because it is your browser, but YouTube does not have access to it.

Comment: they probably use cross site cookies from google ad networks as well.